# Saving the JPA entities in batches- TransactionRequiredException

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, entitymanager

I have the below class to save entities in batches using entity manager:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class AbstractRepositoryAdapter
{
    private static final Logger logger  = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AbstractRepositoryAdapter.class);
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional
    public <O extends GenericEntity> void save(List<O> entities){
        entities.forEach(entity->{
            entityManager.persist(entity);          
        }); 
        System.out.println("saved from save(List<O> entities)");
    }
    @Transactional
    public  <O extends GenericEntity> void write(List<O> entities)
    {
        if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(entities))
        {
            List<List<O>> listOfList = CollectionHelper.split(entities, 1000);

            ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
            List<Future<?>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<?>>();

            for (List<O> subEntities : listOfList)
            {
                Future<?> future = executorService.submit(new BatchExecutor<O>(entityManager, subEntities));
                futures.add(future);
            }

            ObjectHelper.wait(futures.toArray(new Future<?>[0]));// wait until all tasks are finished

            executorService.shutdown();
        }
    }
    @Transactional
    private static class BatchExecutor<O extends GenericEntity> implements Runnable
    {
        private EntityManager em    = null;
        private List<O>         entities    = null;


        public BatchExecutor(EntityManager em, List<O> entities)
        {
            this.em=em;
            this.entities = entities;
        }

        @Override
        @Transactional
        public void run()
        {
            String sql = "";
            try 
            {
                entities.forEach(entity->{
                    em.persist(entity);
                });

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                logger.debug("Unable to save the entities for -> {} ", sql);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

If I try to use the **write** method to save my entity list then I get the below exception:

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No transactional EntityManager available
```

But if I use the **save** method to save my entity list it works fine and the entities are saved to database

But then what is the issue with the code which saves the entities in batches. The Transactional attribute is also present there. Ideally it should work.

**Note**:GenericEntity is the interface which all my entity classes implement.

I wanted to write a multithreaded way of saving the entities which would be generic. But somehow it is not working. If I iterate over the original list and try to save it then it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your `BatchExecutor` instances are not created by Spring so the `@Transactional` annotation on the method has no effect.

Comment: Thanks Strelock .Any other way to do it in batches?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your BatchExecutor is not a Spring bean, so Spring cannot honor that @Transactional annotation  you have there.  The easiest thing is probably to add a Spring bean that is a BatchExecutor factory, so that you can get each BatchExecutor can be a Spring bean.  Something like:

```
@Component
public class BatchExecutorFactory {
    @Lookup <O extends GenericEntity> BatchExecutor<O> getBatchExecutor(EntityManager em, List<O> entities) {
        return new BatchExecutor<O>(em, entities);  // for non-Spring use?
     }

    private class BatchExecutor<O extends GenericEntity> implements Runnable {
        private EntityManager em    = null;
        private List<O>         entities    = null;

        public BatchExecutor(EntityManager em, List<O> entities)
        {
            this.em=em;
            this.entities = entities;
        }

        @Override
        @Transactional
        public void run()
        {
            try 
            {
                entities.forEach(entity->{
                    em.persist(entity);
                });
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Unable to save the entities for -> {} ");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Spring will instantiate this as a bean, replace the implementation of getBatchExecutor() with one that creates a new BatchExecutor as a Spring bean each time you call it, by calling the constructor.

You would need to make your BatchExecutor a prototype-scoped bean.  It already implements Runnable, so Spring can use that interface when proxying your instances.

Comment: I liked this edit - using a template method to tighten the signature of the factory method.  But I usually see these implemented by default as returning null - should it return a new instance (as shown here), for cases where this is used outside Spring?

Comment: Thank you..It was not working. I was waiting for the edit to get approved so that I could ask my question. I injected BatchExecutorFactory in the AbstractRepositoryAdapter class. But then during the getBatchExecutor call it was giving no bean found for BatchExecutor. Can you please help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a configuration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PersistenceJPAConfig{

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean(){
  //...}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(){
  JpaTransactionManager transactionManager
    = new JpaTransactionManager();
  transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(
    entityManagerFactoryBean().getObject() );
  return transactionManager;}}
```